# What are the intended uses of a columnar database?

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have a question about columnar databases such as Sybase. I understand columnar databases are very fast when your operation is restricted to single coulmns and doesn’t go across columns, i.e no row based filtering?

But most queries are a combination of both, filter some rows, then aggregate some columns.

So really, where do columnar databases shine?

Answer (score 1):

Columnar databases can *definitely* access data across different columns.  By storing columns separately, they offer a few advantages not available in row-based storage:

- They only need to read the columns accessed in a particular query.
- They make it easy to add new columns to a table.
- They allow an individual column to be compressed, using a compression algorithm optimal for that column.
- They sometimes provide built-in indexing for each column.

All of these can be used to speed `SELECT` queries.

One big issue with columnar databases is inserting a new row (or deleting a row), because this requires touching all the columns.  That makes ensuring ACID properties . . . trickier.

There are definitely some `SELECT` queries that may not perform as well in a columnar database as in other databases.  But they do surprisingly well at increasing the performance of many queries.

Comment: An example of a poorly performing query might be 

select * from columnar_table

This query has to link all the columns for each row together, this will perform much slower than if only the required columns are specified.

Comment: @RichardCrossley . . . That has to be balanced against two things.  First, the data structures are optimized to find "matching" rows in different columns.  And -- more importantly -- the columns are (typically) compressed so much less data may need to be read.  But you are right that `select *` is an example of a query that may not work as well as expected.

Comment: I totally agree, I just seem to have to explain this sometimes.

Comment: columnar Dbs are considered good for write heavy applications due to their columns based append only structure.